# Mysql search similar integer by partial matching

Tags: mysql, matching

Ok. I'll try to describe my case a bit detailed.
I have asked 6 questions (Yes/No) to 4 users and recorded this answers as string vars (1-Yes, 0-No). So as a result I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `answers` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);
INSERT INTO `answers` VALUES ('1', '111111');
INSERT INTO `answers` VALUES ('2', '111000');
INSERT INTO `answers` VALUES ('3', '110011');
INSERT INTO `answers` VALUES ('4', '100001');
```

Now I'm trying to find results similar to my '111111' result (I answered *Yes* to all questions). Interesting in 50% matching rows.

User #1 has 100% matching answers 111111=111111
User #2 has 50% matching answers 111000 -> 111111
...and so on

So I want to discover what query will find 50% matching rows for me :)

Comment: Can you show us your table schema and sample data set for the same? thanks :) I was thinking you may be referring 110010 as 50 in decimal, but you are doing something different. Please show us your data.

Comment: So literally you have 6 questions. :) That makes sense. And you want to find these percentages based on the pattern of which questions were answered and not. Interesting.

Comment: I want to find the most similar answers. Actually I have 24 questions (6 is just for example here). And each user must have ability to find users with similar answers... For the User #4 the most similar answer is #3 (4 of 6 points are identical ... 67% matching).

Comment: +1 as I am curious :P Your question has two variations, two perspectives one can look at.
1. Get the percentage of any x answers correct. 
  2. Get the percentage of x answers are correct for matching questions. e.g. questions 1, 2, 5 is correct for user A. questions 1,2, 5 corrrect for user B. questions 1,2,6 correct for user C.

Answer (score 1):

After the OP added the schema I have rewritten the answer.

Firstly, this is such a complex problem that it make sense to encapsulate it in a stored function:

```
DELIMITER ;; -- In case you are using PHPMyAdmin or something like that

-- Calculates the number of matching answers between
-- two users, given the total number of answers each user has made
-- Replace 6 everywhere in this function with the number of questions (if it changes)
CREATE FUNCTION NumberOfMatchingAnswers(p_user1 INT, p_user2 INT) RETURNS INT

BEGIN
DECLARE i INT Default 1; -- Loop counter
DECLARE str_user1 VARCHAR(6); 
DECLARE str_user2 VARCHAR(6); 
DECLARE num_matched_answers INT Default 0;

SET str_user1 = LPAD(p_user1,6,'0');
SET str_user2 = LPAD(p_user2,6,'0');

answer_match_loop : LOOP

    IF SUBSTR(str_user1, i, 1) = SUBSTR(str_user2, i, 1) THEN
        SET num_matched_answers = num_matched_answers + 1;
    END IF;

    SET i = i + 1; -- Basically the equivalent of a FOR loop
    IF i > 6 THEN
        LEAVE answer_match_loop;
    END IF;
END LOOP answer_match_loop;

RETURN num_matched_answers;

END;;
```

Now that we have the stored function defined, we can create queries based on it:

```
SELECT user_id FROM Answers WHERE
NumberOfMatchingAnswers(Answers.answers, 101101) >= 3;
```

This query will fetch all the matching `user_id`s that answered the same as `101101` in three or more questions.

So, how can you use this query in your system?

1. Replace `101101` with the actual set of answers you want to compare with
2. If you find that you are getting too many false positives, increase the number `3` so your threashold is above 50%
3. Write a query that finds all pairs of `user_id`s that have a greater than 50% match
4. Etc. etc.

**NOTE**: If you wish to expand your system to not only take yes/no inputs, but actually allow a range of options, this stored function will be able to cope. Because it compares each digit, you can have up to 10 possible answers for each question and it will still work.

Comment: I've added detailed explanaition and mysql table shema. Can you pls write full query?

Comment: So now you are almost ready to create a new internet dating website! :)

Answer (score 1):

[BIT_COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#function_bit-count) should help You.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BIT_COUNT(score)>=3;
```

This query assumes that  You have 6 questions and look for scores with 50%+ score;

if You insert rows like this

```
INSERT INTO `answers` VALUES ('1', b'111111');
```

You don't have to use conv.

To be more precise if You insert scores that way, they will be treated as binary and You may use bitwise operators successfully in Your case.
So if You do e.g.

```
SELECT user_id, BIT_COUNT(answers) FROM answers
```

You will get number of correct answers.
To get +/- 2 points from given score, it would be

```
SELECT user_id FROM answers WHERE BIT_COUNT(answers) BETWEEN BIT_COUNT(score_to_compare_with)-2 AND BIT_COUNT(score_to_compare_with)+2
```

Comment: `bit_count` doesn't seem to work for his case.
e.g. 

(1, '111111') --->bc = 8 and (2, '111000') --->bc = 8

Comment: I thought You wrote those numbers in binary format. Use conv() `BIT_COUNT(conv(score,10,2))` or better treat numbers as binary and change them to 10 base before insertion

Comment: still `BIT_COUNT()` only gives number of correct answers(1s). So your idea could be used as to match for e.g. if any 4 answers are correct, then take the count and %. It will not have exact or nearest % then ;) Coz there are two ways to look at this. But I hope OP could look into these and voice out if it works out for him.

Comment: If You want percentage You write `SELECT user_id, BIT_COUNT(answers)/6 FROM answers WHERE BIT_COUNT(answers)/6 BETWEEN BIT_COUNT(answers)/6-0.1 AND BIT_COUNT(answers)/6+0.1` it will give You +/- 10% when there is 6 questions

Answer (score 0):

The answer I am talking about might be too complicated. However, thought it's best to share.

For all 24 questions you may need to generate a permutaions of correct/wrong answers as patterns.
Keep them store in a table with unique ID for each pattern.

Then you match your current answers table column with that pattern table to get sum, count etc.

Let me rephrase and explain by a sample. This query will give you exact match. But you can do the necessary changes to get a partical match in the event there's no exact match.

### REFERENCE AT : [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/291c8/2)

Your pattern table:

```
ANSWERS     CONV(BINARY ANSWERS,2,10)
111111      63
111000      56
110011      51
100001      33
```

Your answer table:

```
ID  ANSWERS
1   111111
2   111000
3   110011
4   100001
5   111000
```

Query to show the count for each match:

```
select count(*) into @all from scores;
select x.p as b_answer_pattern,
conv(x.p,10,2) as answer_pattern, 
count(x.id)as counts, 
concat(round((count(x.id)/@all)*100,2),'%') as pct
from (
select id, conv(binary answers,2,10) as p
from scores) as x
group by x.p;
```

Results:

```
B_ANSWER_PATTERN    ANSWER_PATTERN  COUNTS  PCT
33                  100001           1      20.00%
51                  110011           1      20.00%
56                  111000           2      40.00%
63                  111111           1      20.00%
```